# spring roo tutorial- undo perform eclipse command

Tags: eclipse, spring-roo

I am following following spring roo tutorial

http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/beginning.html

My problem is I ran `perform eclipse` command without reading full paragraph before. Now, since I am already using STS, I was not supposed to eclipsify my roo project.

Now, how to undo `perform eclipse` command so that I can directly import the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way that I reverted the perform eclipse command was by exiting roo and from the directory where project is I typed

```
mvn eclipse:clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to import the project as a maven project directly, instead of importing a existing project.

If there is any problem with the imported project, try to update the project configuration from the Maven context menu (right click on the project. The exact name of the option depends of the version of the m2eclipse plugin that you have in STS: 0.12 or 1)

Comment: well, it did not have any problem in the first place. But, tutorial says I should not have eclipsified that. So, I was just curious how to undo that. Thanks for the answer, I will look into it. :)

Comment: Both Roo's perform eclipse as well as m2e import project option are actually a call to mvn eclipse:eclipse to generate the eclipse files (.project, .classpath and so on)

Thus you can use mnv eclipse:clean form the console (the OS console, not the Roo console) to delete these files

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in learning mode and have just started, why not simply delete the current project and start over based on the tutorial?

All operations described before the "perform eclipse" command in the referenced tutorial can be completed in less than 10 minutes. That ways you also get to revise the top 5-6 commands of Roo which you just learned and get a clean setup (without any beginner frustrations)